# no module named multiarray python ImportError

Tags: python, windows, importerror

ImportError: No module named multiarray
I keep getting the above error while running my script.I removed a different version of python which was installed under cygwin, but it doesn't work. not even from the command line. copying the multiarray.pyd file into the DLLs folder(C:\Users\myname\Anaconda\DLls) didn't work. what can I do to solve this problem?

environment:
    windows7 64-bit
    Anaconda installed
    python2.7.4
    pyDev (Eclipse)

```
path to numpy:  
C:\Users\myname\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.pyc
path to numpy.core : 
C:\Users\myname\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.pyc
path to numpy.core.multiarray : 
C:\Users\myname\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.pyd
```

Comment: Please show your `sys.path`, and a piece of code where you try to import the module

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?  Import errors like this are usually caused by a module name collision with the local package/module.

Comment: >>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda', 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages','C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']

Comment: I don't need to import multiarray separately since it is included in numpy.core, but as it gives an error I import it.                                                                import cPickle
import gzip
import os
import sys
import time
import numpy
import multiarrayimport theano
import theano.tensor as T
from theano.tensor.shared_randomstreams import RandomStreams

from logistic_sgd import LogisticRegression, load_data
from mlp import HiddenLayer
from rbm import RBM

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\theano_mydata\DBN.py", line 416, in <module>
    test_DBN()
  File "C:\Users\myname\theano_mydata\DBN.py", line 291, in test_DBN
    datasets = load_data(dataset)
  File "C:\Users\myname\theano_mydata\logistic_sgd.py", line 177, in load_data
    train_set, valid_set, test_set = cPickle.load(f)
ImportError: No module named multiarray